# “init terminating in do_boot” Windows 8.1 Rabbit MQ fails to start

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I install `erl7.3` and `rabbitmq_server-3.6.1`,but I get the follow error when I run `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp`.

```
{ "init terminating in do_boot", { undef, [{ rabbit_nodes, ensure_epmd, [], [] }, { rabbit_ cli, start_distribution, 0, [{ file, "src/rabbit_cli.erl" }, { line, 152 }] }, { rabbit_cli, e nsure_cli_distribution, 0, [{ file, "src/rabbit_cli.erl" }, { line, 49 }] }, { rabbit_cli, ma in , 3, [{ file, "src/rabbit_cli.erl" }, { line, 62 }] }, { init, start_it, 1, [{ file, "init.erl" }, { line, 1054 }] }, { init, start_em, 1, [{ file, "init.erl" }, { line, 1035 }] }] } }

init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Is there anything I'm missing?How can I fix the `init terminating in do_boot` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I pointed the installer for erlang at the Root of the drive and for saftey RabbitMQ as well and it worked.

simple as that (see attached).[image: RabbitMQ running]

I boiled it down to the space in Program Files... it took me 2 days to work this out and everyone else who was having problems is on linux using non UTF8 charsets.

If I could be bothered, I would work out if the problem was with erlang or RabbitMQ and cry into the arms of that community.

Comment: Thx, I change the path `D:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1` to `D:\RbbbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1` and now it's work well.

Comment: @qqxufo, so you left the Erlang install as is?

Comment: I have installed erl7.3.And I find the [Official Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html)
 `This is because we need to pass the location of the compiled Erlang files to the Erlang VM. It expects input in UTF-8, but the console will typically use some other encoding.`

Comment: Installed on Windows 7, no problems... mine was on windows 10, must be an 8+ issue!?

Comment: I am not sure.May be is 8+ issuel.

Answer (score 3):

On the same error, on Windows 7 :

- If I use in the installation path of the RabbitMQ Server space characters (i.e. D:\soft\RabbitMQ Server), the same error occured ({ "init terminating in do_boot", { undef, [{ rabbit_nodes,...) .
- If the installation path doesn't contain space char (i.e. D:\soft\RabbitMQServer), then no error and RabbitMQ works fine.

So the problem is due for many people to the space in paths of default settings of the RabbitMQ installation program on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I tried several other fixes and removing the space in the installation path is the only thing that worked. RabbitMQ is great but it's insane that this is still a problem in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I upgraded RabbitMQ and forgot to upgrade Erlang. After upgrading Erlang everything worked fine (and my RabbitMQ is installed in `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server`).